# Is square root of a matrix necessarily Cholesky decomposition? Or other decomposition satisfies?

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

If $a$ is a scalar, $a = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}$, then if A is a matrix, $A=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}$, now I think the square root operator is applied to the matrix instead of a scalar. 
Is square root of a matrix necessarily Cholesky decomposition? Or other decomposition satisfies, like QR decomposition? Because $A=QR$ where Q and R are two terms like $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}$. Or does the square roots have to satisfy the condition that one is the other's conjugate transpose as in Cholesky decomposition?

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ can at all be called a square root of $A$, then $B^2=A$, whether we are taking about matrices or anything else. For matrices, there can be infinitely many distinct square roots (even for the zero matrix), but they all satisfy the same equation and no other conditions are necessary.

Comment: the $B^2=A$ definition makes sense, I got a question, do B's have to be equal? Because Cholesky decomposition $L, L*$ aren't exactly equal.

Comment: @user Yes, they have to be equal. It has nothing to do with Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: The reason I kept referring to Cholesky decomposition is that I've read about unscented Kalman filter, and it finds sigma points by finding the $\sqrt{\Sigma}$ and  $\sqrt{\Sigma}$ is always said to be calculated by Cholesky decomposition. Is it because this square root is just a symbolic representation, and not exactly the square root B in $B^2 =A$?

Comment: @user Does the matrix have real entries?

Comment: @user https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix Confusingly, the matrix in the Cholesky decomposition is called a square root even though it isn't.

Comment: Typicall $\Sigma$ are just positive semidefinite matrix, and all real entries.